# Is there a slight difference in the this Remix Version of Alan Jackson's Chattahoocee?

Tags: country, remix

I have been a huge country music fan for 13 years now. I have been adding a lot of artists in my country music collection.

The artist I'm working to add in my country music collection is Alan Jackson. Now, I only buy Compilation albums and CD singles if there is a remix version, radio version or a brand new recording.

I came across a [German release CD single version](https://www.discogs.com/Alan-Jackson-Chattahoochee/release/2417471) of his 1992 chart topper ***Chattahoochee***. Now, I know the difference between the Extended Mix (3:56) that is featured on his 1st Compilation Album ***The Greatest Hits Collection*** and the Extended Remix (4:06) that is featured on his 4th Album ***Who I Am*** on the International version only as a bonus track.

Is there a slight difference on this German single remix (Instrumentation, Vocals etc.) cause the running time says 3:06. I am asking because I thought about buying it.

Comment: Hi CountryBoy94. Your question is somewhat unclear. Are you referring to three different recordings of the song or just two?

Comment: Well specifically I'm referring to 2 different recordings saying i know what the difference is between the Extended Mix & Extended Remix of Chattahoochee. The 4:06 version is the music video version while the extended mix has no motorboat

Comment: The remix version is slightly different but i don't know what is so different about the one from the Germany CD Single

Answer (score 1):

The original version of the song comes from the album [*A Lot About Livin' (And A Little 'Bout Love)*](https://www.discogs.com/Alan-Jackson-A-Lot-About-Livin-And-A-Little-Bout-Love/master/491336) (1992), and lasts 2:27.

The remixed song from the [German single](https://www.discogs.com/Alan-Jackson-Chattahoochee/release/2417471) is surely extended to 3:06 like you said. I couldn't find a link to listen to this version, but be sure you'll have **39 seconds more** than the original version.

Comment: thanks for trying to look for the remix recording. I might buy the Germany Single.Whenever I buy the cd, I'll give an update about what's so different about it.